# Tools to analyze memory allocation patterns in linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management, profiling, trace

Do you guys know any good tools to analyze/visualize memory allocation patterns of programs running in Linux?

I would like to know if there are any specific patterns over the lifetime; like a big allocation phase at the beginning, then some maintenance and a big free at the end. Also nice to know would be, if the program allocates/frees many 'objects' of the same size... like tree-nodes or something.

Comment: ok, that may do. Never saw the heap-analyzer. Lets see how that works.

Comment: What it the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have to do some "realistic" measurements for a project that I do for a class, so I wanted to know how a "typical" application behaves in this manner.